# Circle Detection via Basler Camera and Simulink

Tags: geometry, simulink, detection

Firstly, I am new user for Simulink.

I have a Basler aca2440-75um camera and I need detect the circles from live video on Simulink.

I can run the Basler camera on Simulink using the Image Acquisition Toolbox and I can do edge detection thanks to a method I found on the internet. Blocks which I used are;

from video device
edge detection (prewitt)
compositing (highlight)
to video display

After edge detection thanks to these blocks, what do I need to do for circle detection? What blocks should I add? I'd really appreciate it if you could help me in detail.

Kind regards

Comment: Is it possible to use Hough circle detection with Simulink?

Comment: I could not see any Hough circle detection block on Simulink. Am I missing something?

Comment: I know nothing about simulink but this algo is intended to detect circles